# How to install Microsoft Spec# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, spec#

On MS-Research Microsoft has a C#-compatible language called Spec#.
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

I found installer .msi only for Visual Studio 2008.
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/8826adb9-8398-40d6-a22d-951923fe2647/

I found (don't remember where) and downloaded zip-package for Spec# 2010 but i found no installer.

How to install Microsoft Spec# in Visual Studio 2010?
is it also possible to work with Visual Studio C# Express and Spec#?

thanks in advance
Oops

Answer (score 3):

This discussion should help you: http://specsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/230181